# Behavior of `=` in alloy fact

Tags: alloy

I was experimenting with alloy and wrote this code.

```
one sig s1{
    vals: some Int
}{
#vals = 4
}

one sig s2{
    vals: some Int
}{
#vals = 4
}

fact {
    all a : s1.vals | a > 2
    all i : s2.vals | i < 15
    s1.vals = s2.vals
}

pred p{}
run p
```

It seems to me that {3,4,5,6} at least is a solution however Alloy says no instance found. When I comment `s1.vals = s2.vals` or change `i < 15` to `i > 2`, it finds instances.

Can anyone please explain me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alloy's relationship with integers is sometimes mildly strained; it's not designed for heavily numeric applications, and many uses of integers in conventional programming are better handled in Alloy by other signatures.

The default bit width for integers is 4 bits, and Alloy uses twos-complement integers, so your `run p` is asking for a world in which integers range in value from -8 to 7.  In that world, the constraint `i < 15` is subject to integer overflow, and turns out to mean, in effect, `i < -1`.  (To see this, comment out both of your constraints so that you get some instances.  Then (a) leaf through the instances produced by the Analylzer and look at the integers that appear in them; you'll see their range is as I describe.  Also, (b) open the Evaluator and type the numeral "15"; you'll see that its value in this universe is -1.)

If you change your `run` command to provide an appropriate bit width for integers (e.g. `run p for 5 int`), you'll get instances which are probably more like what you were expecting.

An alternative change, however, which leads to a more idiomatic Alloy model, is to abstract away from the specific kind of value by defining a sig for values:

```
sig value {}
```

Then change the declaration for `vals` in s1 and s2 from `some Int` to `some value`, and comment out the numeric constraints on them (or substitute some other interesting constraints for them).  And then run p in a suitable scope (e.g. `run p for 8 value`).

Comment: Thank you, I tried constraining i with other numbers (the lowest i tried was 9) as well and they all were negative. Now I understand why :)